# Kafka consumer group fails to read data from one/more partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are using 3 kafka consumers with same group id to read data.
Kafka topic with `--replication-factor 5` and `--partitions 5`

Initially all works fine, but after some time (say after 1 week), consumer group fails to read data from one or more partitions. We don't see any error being logged.

We use kafka version = 0.10.0.1

Any help here will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is your retention policy by topic? is it possible that consumer is subscribed to a topic having offset which is deleted?

When you saying "fails to read" can you post some logs on consumer side? What happens when you

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic awesomeTopic --from-beginning --consumer-property group.id=consumerGroup
```

Comment: Thanks for response Akim. We have retention of 90 days. Offset are not deleted. But i can see a lag in the consumer offset after every day run, though we commit message after reading it. When i run the command given by you, it read some old messages...

Comment: We dont do auto commit. We Read the message and we process the message. this operation will take some time say, 1 minute. Then we commit the message. Will this Delay in committing offset cause any problem?

Comment: Our application Runs only at every day night. So it is idle for the rest of the time. Will this affect the kakfa offset?